# Seaborn、matplotlib.pyplotの略称

Tags: matplotlib

なぜseabornはsnsと略すんですか？
また、matplotlibがpltやmplと略されているのを見ますがどちらが一般的なのでしょうか？

Answer (score 2):

・sns
[ここ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41499857/seaborn-why-import-as-sns)からリンクをたどれますが、snsはSeabornという名前を持つキャラクターのイニシャルだそうです。
[Samuel Norman "Sam" Seaborn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sam_Seaborn)

・pltとmpl
matplotlib.pyplotならplt, matplotならmplかなと。

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl
```